# set variable as an input whose parent's index matches another variable

Tags: jquery

I have a webform where I am trying to manipulate the value of some readonly text inputs based on dropdown selections.

HTML (abbreviated) basically looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="container">
    <fieldset class="foo-points-fs">
        <div>
            <selector id="foo-bar1-points">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </selector>
        </div>
        <div>
            <selector id="foo-bar2-points">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
            </selector>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="foo-weight-fs">
        <div>
            <input readonly="readonly" value="1" id="foo-bar1-weight"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input readonly="readonly" value="2" id="foo-bar2-weight"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="foo-score-fs">
        <div>
            <input readonly="readonly" value="0" id="foo-bar1-score"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input readonly="readonly" value="0" id="foo-bar2-score"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

On the page, these basically look like table rows where you have a column of dropdowns the user will select from with columns for weight and score next to it. So each set of `selector`, `input`, and `input` is one row.

What I would like to do is change the value of the inputs within the `.score` fieldset according to the value of the selector and weight input in the same row – i.e., those whose parent divs' indexes are equal to their corresponding selector's parent div's index.

The part I am having trouble figuring out is how to say, in jQuery, to set a variable to "the input whose parent div's index is equal to another selector/input's parent div's index."

Here's what I've got so far:

```
jQuery('fieldset.container select[id$="-points"]').change(function() {

    var sel = jQuery(this),
        fs = sel.parents('fieldset[id$="-points-fs"]'),
        dropPar = sel.parent('div'),
        dropNdx = dropPar.index(),
        weightInput = fs.find('input[id$="-weight]'),
        scoreInput = fs.find('input[id$="-score"]'),
        weight = weightInput.parent('div').index(dropNdx), // problem is here, I assume
        score = scoreInput.parent('div').index(dropNdx); // problem is here, I assume

  score.val(weight.val() * sel.val());

});
```

Help please?

Comment: Hey can you create a fiddle? - http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code!

```js
jQuery('fieldset.webform-component--rubric--part1.form-wrapper select[id$="-points"]').change(function() {
 
   var value = $(this).val();
    var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    var weight = $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find('#pid'+index+'-weight').val();
  
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().next().find('#pid'+index+'-score').val( value*weight );
  
});
```

```css
.description, select {
  display: inline;
}
.description {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
fieldset fieldset {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="webform-component--rubric--part1 form-wrapper">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
        <div></div> <!-- unrelated -->
        <fieldset class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid">
            <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                <div></div>
                <div> <!-- unrelated -->
                    <div><div></div></div> <!-- unrelated -->
                    <div><div></div></div> <!-- unrelated -->
                    <div><div></div></div> <!-- unrelated -->
                    <div><div></div></div> <!-- unrelated -->
                </div>
                <fieldset class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-points-fs">
                    <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-points-fs--ahcp-pid1-points">
                        <div class="description">1.</div>
                        <select id="pid1-points" name="pid1_points" class="form-select">
                          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-points-fs--ahcp-pid2-points">
                        <div class="description">2.</div>
                        <select id="pid2-points" name="pid2_points" class="form-select">
                          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-points-fs--ahcp-pid3-points">
                        <div class="description">3.</div>
                        <select id="pid3-points" name="pid3_points" class="form-select">
                          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-points-fs--ahcp-pid4-points">
                        <div class="description">4.</div>
                        <select id="pid4-points" name="pid4_points" class="form-select">
                          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                  </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-weight-fs">
                    <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-weight-fs--ahcp-pid1-weight">
                          <label>1. Weight</label>
                          <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="pid1-weight" name="pid1_weight" value="1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-weight-fs--ahcp-pid2-weight">
                          <label>2. Weight</label>
                          <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="pid2-weight" name="pid2_weight" value="2" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-weight-fs--ahcp-pid3-weight">
                          <label>3. Weight</label>
                          <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="pid3-weight" name="pid3_weight" value="2" />
                        </div>
                        <div readonly="readonly" class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-weight-fs--ahcp-pid4-weight">
                          <label>4. Weight</label>
                          <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="pid4-weight" name="pid4_weight" value="3" />
                        </div>
                  </div>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-score-fs">
                    <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-score-fs--ahcp-pid1-score">
                          <label>1. Score</label>
                          <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="pid1-score" name="pid1_weight" value="0" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-score-fs--ahcp-pid2-score">
                          <label>2. Score</label>
                          <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="pid2-score" name="pid2_weight" value="0" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-score-fs--ahcp-pid3-score">
                          <label>3. Score</label>
                          <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="pid3-score" name="pid3_weight" value="0" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="webform-component--rubric--part1--row-pid--pid-score-fs--ahcp-pid4-score">
                          <label>4. Score</label>
                          <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="pid4-score" name="pid4_weight" value="0" />
                        </div>
                  </div>
               </fieldset>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was gonna do something more like that originally, but I could not figure out how to do the `.find()` part. The examples on jquery.com are never that complex; wasn't sure if that was acceptable or not. Thanks for teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 0):

This code worked on your pen:

```
jQuery('fieldset.webform-component--rubric--part1.form-wrapper select[id$="-points"]').change(function() {
  // get select value
  var value = jQuery(this).val();
  // get select id
  var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  // use replace to get clear digit from id
  var num = id.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
  // build selector for wight based on num and get its value * select value
  var score = value * jQuery('#pid'+num+'-weight').val();
  // build selector for score based on num and set the value
  jQuery('#pid'+num+'-score').val(score);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I had thought about doing something like this, but I think an approach that doesn't rely on the ID would be more flexible for me in the future. Even still, I am curious to understand this code because I don't think I'm following. It seems to me that the number in the selector ID is being completely stripped out by the `num` variable, but that is the only unique part of that string. Otherwise all input/selector IDs would match exactly. So how does this still work and not end up changing all score inputs at once?

Comment: I've added comments in the code for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you. That is basically what I thought was going on, but I think I just do not understand the regex syntax completely. The empty pair of single quotes after the regex is what is confusing me. I'll have to read up on it some more, I guess.

Comment: Here is good tool for learn and test regex - [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)